# Convert Unicode to UTF 32

Tags: unicode, utf-32

How I convert `U+0065` to UTF-32 format ?

```
U+0065
0000 0000 0110 0101

UTF-32
xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxxx
```

Convert U+0065 to UTF-32:

```
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 0101
```

Result in hex is `0x00000065`

Is that correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

UTF-32 is always written using 32 bits. Unicode defines codepoints up to U+10FFFF, which uses 21 bits. So a UTF-32 value is always the same as the codepoint itself.

Because U+0065 is in the U+0000..U+007F range, it is written in UTF-8 using 8 bits (`01100101`).  In UTF-16, it is the same using 16 bits (`00000000 01100101`), and in UTF-32 using 32 bits (`00000000 00000000 00000000 01100101`).

Comment: There may be an issue with the endianness. UTF-16BE and UTF-32BE are big-endian (like in the examples above), while UTF-16LE and UTF-32LE are the little-endian counterparts, in which case the bytes would be in the reverse order. UTF-32 without suffix may mean two different things: 1) UTF-32BE (big-endian byte order as default); 2) native endianness of the machine (almost certainly UTF-32LE on a PC). Thus it is better always to use the suffix BE or LE.